# how to split the string by using comma in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to split string by comma by using mysql function..I am very new for mysql and their function and I was created function and pass the string to that function..

String as `ABC,CDEFG123,XYZ`.

How to Split above string by comma using the loop??.

My request is:

```
Select * from TABLE where Column = 'ABC',
Select * from TABLE1 Where column1 = 'CDEF134'
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where column2 = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: MySQL is very bad at this sort of thing. If you're doing this you probably need to rethink your database design and use separate columns or a table instead of a comma-separated list.

Comment: How are you passing this to MySQL? Why wouldn't you split the string up before it gets there?

Comment: Compare the values with different columns as well different table...it is the water flow process..so that I am getting comma separated output...

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy in MySQL:

```
Select * from TABLE where Column = substring_index('ABC,CDEFG123,XYZ', ',', 1);
Select * from TABLE1 Where column1 = substring_index('ABC,CDEFG123,XYZ', ',', 2), ',', -1)
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where column2 = substring_index('ABC,CDEFG123,XYZ', ',', -1)
```

Comment: @miken32 . . . That's interesting.  I actually got an error the first couple of times I tried to post the answer.

Comment: Thanks gordon...but how it is works when giving more number of comma separated input??input not exactly 3.it may vary..

Comment: @VenkateshKuppusamy . . . Your question is about lists with three elements.  You can easily extend the logic for the second element to get any element (just change the "2" to whatever element you want).  If that doesn't solve your problem, then ask another question and try to be quite clear about what you are looking for.